# Please help me with think of a better algorithm in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some Events, People. There is a many-to-many relationship between them so there is a PersonEvent connecting Events to People.

Event has a date and type

PersonEvent has an event_id and a person_id

Person has a name

I'm trying to build a search form that allows the user to search by the type of an Event, and then returns a list of People who attended a Event of that type in the past and the last date they attended such an Event. This should be in the controller.

The only solution I can think of involves nested loops and will probably run very slowly. I'm definitely looping through a lot of things I don't need to be.

```
For each person in Person.all
    For each personevent in PersonEvent.all
        Add the personevent to an array if the person_event.event.type is correct
    Now, loop through the array and find the event with the latest date. That's the date of the last Event attendance.
```

Can anyone suggest a better algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the associations already set up you should be able to do something like:

```
f = Person.joins(:events)
f = f.where(:events => { :type => "the_type_you_are_searching_for" })
f = f.group('people.id')
f = f.select('people.*, max(events.date) as last_event_date')
people = f.all # though you probably want to paginate really
```

I've done it line by line to make it easier to read in here but often you'd see the `where`, `group` and `select` chained together one after the other on the same line.

You need the `group` otherwise you'll get people returned multiple times if they have been to multiple events.

The custom `select` is to include the `last_event_date` in the results.

Answer (score 3):

In RoR, it would be:

```
Person.joins(:events).where(events: { type: params[:type] })
```

Rails `joins` will create an `INNER JOIN`, which will discard people who don't have an associated event that meets the criteria in `where`.

You don't explain how your keeping the date of attendance information, so I'll leave that bit up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a custom SQL query? It would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM person_events 
INNER JOIN people ON people.id = person_events.person_id
INNER JOIN events ON events.id = person_events.event_id AND events.type = 'EventType'
```